# Manipulating and using String obtained from Arduino USB

Tags: android, logging, usb

I can get the string coming from USB serial working when it is in raw format. but as soon as I try to use Double.valueOf or other methods to convert it to number the app crashes.

```
public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
    String data = null;
    try {
        data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");

       Double waterLevel=Double.valueOf(data);

        tvAppend(textView, waterLevel+"m");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

The above works when using this and only trying to convert String to Double or Float causes trouble:

```
   String waterLevel=data+"m";
```

Error message:

```
2019-02-05 19:02:06.746 915-5126/? E/AwareLog: CPUFeatureAMSCommunicator: set app boost but type is unknown
2019-02-05 19:02:06.824 421-450/? E/DynamicFpsPolicy: FpsInfo: 1a500000000 can not find FpsPolicyService
2019-02-05 19:02:07.683 915-1498/? E/TouchFilter: setTouchFilter LOG Enable prameter: 0
2019-02-05 19:02:08.237 421-450/? E/DynamicFpsPolicy: FpsInfo: 1a500000000 can not find FpsPolicyService
2019-02-05 19:02:08.454 12270-12270/com.jorc.loggergeneral.jorclogger E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-02-05 19:02:08.455 12270-12270/com.jorc.loggergeneral.jorclogger E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-02-05 19:02:09.432 12270-12467/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
    Process: com.jorc.loggergeneral.jorclogger, PID: 12270
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
        at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:503)
        at com.jorc.loggergeneral.jorclogger.MainActivity$1.onReceivedData(MainActivity.java:55)
        at com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialDevice$WorkerThread.onReceivedData(UsbSerialDevice.java:209)
        at com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialDevice$WorkerThread.run(UsbSerialDevice.java:184)
2019-02-05 19:02:09.483 915-1082/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '4af7ed1 com.jorc.loggergeneral.jorclogger/com.jorc.loggergeneral.jorclogger.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-02-05 19:02:09.535 421-450/? E/DynamicFpsPolicy: FpsInfo: 1a500000000 can not find FpsPolicyService
2019-02-05 19:02:09.706 915-1284/? E/TouchFilter: setTouchFilter LOG Enable prameter: 0
2019-02-05 19:02:09.938 1135-1135/? E/FullInputEventModel: onStartInput event aborted: ejh: could not obtain extracted text (class ejh)
2019-02-05 19:02:10.976 485-485/? E/Thermal-daemon: [battery] temp_new :32  temp_old :31
2019-02-05 19:02:10.979 485-485/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [battery] temp :32  report_threshold:1
2019-02-05 19:02:11.731 915-1284/? E/TouchFilter: setTouchFilter LOG Enable prameter: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in the stacktrace. You try to parse an empty string. 
Try using a debugger sometime...

Comment: It is not an empty string. I can see values when simply adding to text view.

Comment: I tried adding this which then works for a couple of values and then does the same thing.                 if (!data. isEmpty()){test=Double.valueOf(data);}

Answer (score 0):

I could handle the problem using catch phrase. You cant just avoid it using if phrase in first line:

```
    if(data.length()!=0 && data.length()>0){
        try {
                tvAppend(textView, Double.parseDouble(data)*6 + "m\n");
         } catch(Exception e) {
            // or some value to mark this field is wrong. or make a function
        }
    }
```